# Check if Element/ID/Class is Added Before Append

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/palavuso/1/edit

You start with a blank canvas. Click the add button and **BAM**.... we have a button

```
$(".add-query").on('click', function() {
  $(".beauty-btns").append("<a class='" + $('.mediaquery-slider').val() + "' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + $('.mediaquery-slider').val() + "px</a>");

  // Remove Query
  $(".beauty-btns").find("a").on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Simple I know; However what if the class or ID already exists?
Well if it's a class we can add multiple, but not in my experiment.

What I'm trying to do is add the button, but if the class already exists alert the user and ask them if they want to replace the button or cancel.

I know I can use `window.confirm` for the alert process here, but after that I'm confused.

**Example:**

```
    var x = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to refresh the page?")
    if (x)
      location.reload(true);
    else
      return false;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to place yourself in our position when asking a question like this, we have **no idea** what this project is and what it does. Your question, as it stands, at least assumes some understanding of it. It is absolutely unclear. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'll revise the question explaining more about how this works. Which should make it easier for the community to understand. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, it's just for your own sake of increasing your chances of getting help. Also note that you should probably make your question as short as possible, make it more specific and ask questions about specific jQuery tasks. Questions that ask for general help with improving a project aren't usually received well.

Comment: Sounds like a much better way to go to. I'll revise my question again and keep it at a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a class exists, simply select it and see if there is anything with `length`:

```
var val = $('.mediaquery-slider').val();
var $button = $(".beauty-btns").find('a.' + val);
//notice the . after a for "select by class".

//$button is supposed to contain an array of matches, length = 0 with no match
if($button.length > 0) {
    alert("Button already exists!");
}
```

Now for the code about replacing it, you almost have it:

```
var x = window.confirm("Button exists, replace it?") //will give OK/Cancel buttons
if (x)
  $button.replaceWith("<a class='" + $('.mediaquery-slider').val() + "' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + $('.mediaquery-slider').val() + "px</a>");
else
  return false; //Depending on the situation you could just leave off the else block.
```

**Notes**

- Your classes will start with a number if I'm not mistaken. This is not valid. Prepend a letter instead:

  ```
  var val = 'button-' + $('.mediaquery-slider').val();
  ```
- It's actually better to use ID's in your case as supposedly there can only be one button for each slider value.
- I don't really see why you would want to replace the buttons. After all,you replace them with the exact same HTML. You **would** lose all the event handlers and other javascript data on them. And now that I notice, you're attaching handlers in a wrong way!

Store the class that you used for appending the last button, and then only set a click handler on that one:

```
$(".beauty-btns").find("a." + val).on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

If you don't do this, every existing button will keep getting new click handlers everytime you add one. That's not efficient in terms of memory and performance.